# How I do bind data to DisplayFor from event blur on asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, blur

I'm using event blur for lost focus on textbox. But I only bind data to textboxfor cannot bind data to labelfor or displayfor. How can I do ?

My java script:

```
$('#PGId').blur(function () {
        var errormsg = "";
        var id = $('#PGId').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetDetailPG", "TimeSheetHeader")',
            data: { pgId: id },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#FirstName").val(data.FisrtName)
                $("#LastName").val(data.LastName)
                $("#Shiff").val(data.ShiffId)
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                $('#error').html("Primitive Functions not allowed.")
            }
        });
    })
```

My razor view:

```
<div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PGId) <em>( * )</em>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PGId, new { @class = "form-control input-sm", @name = "normal" })
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstName) @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Shiff)
                <div>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Shiff, "M") Morning
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Shiff, "N") Night
                    </label>
                </div>
                <span style="color:red" class="help-block">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Shiff)</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Html.DisplayFor()` does not generate an element with an `id` attribute, nor a control with a `value` attribute so you can't use `$("#FirstName").val(data.FirstName)`. Instead create a container element with the required `id` and update its contents in the ajax call (not sure what `ShiffId` is - you didn't show any html for it)

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PGId, new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
<div id="firstname">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FirstName)</div>
<div id="lastname">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.LastName)</div>
```

then in the script

```
success: function (data) {
  $("#firstname").text(data.FirstName)
  $("#lastname").text(data.LastName)
},
```

Note also you should be using the `change` event of the textbox (not `blur`) to avoid unnecessary calls to the server when the user is just tabbing through controls.

Side note: Why are you trying to override the `name` attribute of the textbox for property `PGId`?

**Edit**

Based on OP edit showing html for `ShiffId`, to update the radio button, add a class name to the radio buttons (note: `class` attribute added for easier selection and `id` attribute added so no duplicates)

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Shiff, "M", new { id = "shiff-m", @class = "shiff" })
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Shiff, "N", new { id = "shiff-n", @class = "shiff" })
```

and replace `$("#Shiff").val(data.ShiffId)` with (assumes `data.Shiff` will be either "M" or "N")

```
$('.shiff[value="' + data.Shiff + '"]').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: Hi @Stephen Muecke. I have just updated code in my question. How can I bind data to radiobuttonfor ???

Comment: @KhiemNguyen, Answer updated for selecting the appropriate radio button

Comment: I have tried run your code but It always default bind data to 'model => model.Shiff, "M"'

Comment: Are you sure that `data.Shiff` is either "M" or "N"? (it's case sensitive!). You could always do `var shiff = data.Shiff.toUpperCase(); $('.shiff[value="' + shiff + '"]').prop('checked', true);` if the data your returning could be lower case (or ensure its converted to upper case in the controller)

Comment: Your code is right. I have had a mistake basic, I have edited code in controller and I forget ctr + shift + F5 for my project :)

Comment: I have just find another solution for me you can check link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718263/mvc3-text-box-text-change-event but I don't know What is the best solution for me in my issue ?

Comment: That really depends on whether your just displaying information or need to edit the first and last name. If you need to edit the first and last name, then use `@Html.TextBoxFor()` in which case your previous code was OK - i.e. `$("#FirstName").val(data.FirstName);`.

Comment: It may also depend on what you want to post back. If you want to post back the `FirstName` and `LastName` properties (using a standard form submit) then you will need a control, but you can always use a readonly textbox if you don't want it to be editable

Comment: I have more a problem in my code that when I open new tab on browser and Update LastName or FirstName after I come back tab display information and type PGID and hit tab my data not change. If I close my browser and open again it works exactly

Comment: You have not given enough information to understand the problem. You need to ask a new question with the relevant code and explain the issue.